# Connecting to Node JS Server: Works with Desktops, Not iPhone

Tags: node.js

I have a node js server running on my laptop which is connected to my home network via Wifi. I can connect using the IP address `192.168.10.108:8080` on both the laptop running the server and another desktop on the same network (ethernet). However, I cannot connect using my iPhone which is connected to the same network via Wifi.

I changed my script according to results I found while searching for the issue but it hasn't solved my problem `app.listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");`

I've also tried turning off my Firewall to see if that was blocking the connection but it did not solve the problem.

What else can I try so that my iPhone will connect to the node js server?